# Let $(\Omega, F, P)$ be a probability space with $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$. and $F=\{\emptyset , \{2, 4, 6\}, \{1, 3, 5\}, \Omega \}$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, F, P)$ be a probability space with $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$. and $F=\{\emptyset , \{2, 4, 6\}, \{1, 3, 5\}, \Omega \}$. Let $U$ be a function on $\Omega$ defined as $U(w)=5w+32$. Is $U$ a random variable?

It is supposed to satisfy that for any $w$, $(U\leq w) \in F$. I do not understand this condition.

It is possible that I am misunderstanding it, but I think that $U$ is not a random variable.

Comment: Does the set $\{U\leq 37\}$ belong to $F$?

Comment: $U\leq 37$ is the condition. Well, I don't understand very well.

Comment: To be more precise, does the set $\{\omega\in\Omega: U(\omega)\leq 37\}$ belongs to $F$? If not then $U$ is clearly not a random variable.

Comment: @Mark Then, one has that that set is $\{1\}$, and it does not belong to $F$.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.